# ScrollTo() method doesn't work when WebView inside ScrollView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, scrollview

I have WebView which is loading **HTML** with **JS**. From **WebView** I call **JS** function which is looking for some text in HTML. In this function I have command which is scrolling WebView to the next match text:

```
window.scrollTo(0, y);
```

If I place WebView **inside** ScrollView (like in the code below), WebView will not scroll (even command `webView.scrollTo(x,y)` doesn't scroll it). But if I place it **outside** ScrollView - scrolling to the next position works fine.
But I have to use **WebView** inside **ScrollView**.

Please, help me to solve this problem. What I have to do?
This is my layout code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/articleScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/articleBodyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_main_article"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/article_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/article_web_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textSize="16dp">
            </WebView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is code of activity method where **JS** is called:

```
public void searchInText(View view) {
    final String textToSearch = editTextSearchInText.getText().toString();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    article_web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, issue.getHtmlBody(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "UTF-8");

    article_web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('" + textToSearch + "')");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use scrollTo() method for web view inside scroll view because ***if you use the web view under scroll view then all scrolling functions will be applied for its parent (for scroll view) *** so we will have to applied method on our parent scroll view instead of web view.

So use the fullScroll() method of scroll view. So apply below line for your scroll view.

**For scrolling Top>>**

```
 YourScrollView.fullScroll(yourScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

**For scrolling down>>**

```
YourScrollView.fullScroll(yourScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```